# Is it possible to customise UITableView's reorder icon to locate at left side?

Tags: ios, swift

It is possible to customise `UITableView` edit mode to certain extend.

By conform the following protocol funcions

```
// MARK: Customization

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return false
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    return UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.none
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath
}
```

We are able to have something as

[image]

---

Currently, our requirement is that, the reoder icon (icon with 3 horizontal lines) should be at left side. It should look as

[image]

I was wondering, during `UITableView` edit mode, is it ever possible to customise the reorder icon on left side?

Answer (score 0):

In the cell's `willDisplayCell` you can iterate through the cell's subviews until you find the reorder control.  Create a new subview the same size as the control and place it where you want, then add the reorder control as a subview of the subview you created and center it on it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.subviews.forEach { (subview) in
        if String(describing: type(of: subview.self)) == "UITableViewCellReorderControl" {
            let control = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: subview.frame.size))
            control.addSubview(subview)
            subview.center = control.center
            cell.contentView.addSubview(control)
        }
    }
}
```